# NSNetServiceBrowser not able to discover the UDP base service

Tags: ios, objective-c, bonjour

I have been trying to figure out the exact issue. I have two UDP base services running on my local Wifi network. My Bojour discovery app NOT able to discover one of the service(**Real**) 3 out of 10 times. Where as it discover the other service(**Simulation**) 10 out of 10 times.

When i run this command

```
dns-sd -B _coap._udp.
```

on terminal, its showing me both of the services. Then why my app failing to discover the Real service some of the times.

Comment: There is a bug! Fix it!